# MySQL order by DESC hangs; ASC is fine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, easyphp

I have a simple MySQL database table with just 20 records. The `ID` column is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `integer` which is set as the primary key.

This code is trying to fetch the most recent entry from the table, using a PDO object:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM latest_news ORDER BY ID ASC";

$pdo=connectToDatabase();
$result=$pdo->query($query);

$newsStory=$result->fetch();
```

This code works fine when I'm sorting ascending `ORDER BY ID ASC`, but when I sort descending `ORDER BY ID DESC`, it hangs and loses connection. No PHP error message is displayed; the page never loads in the browser, even after a long wait.

Environment is PHP 5.4.45, MySQL 5.6.27 and a local web server using EasyPHP 14.1

Of course, if any more information is needed, please let me know. Still fairly new to MySQL queries.

Comment: can you send your hang query?

Comment: Of course, we hope you mean `ORDER BY ID DESC` (with **ID**). Also, you want to check the return value of `query()` and log errors should it be false.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; edited the question.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy - what is a hang query? Sorry, still a newcomer to this.

Comment: I mean the query that make the page hangs

Comment: That minor of a change to a query should not cause that sort of issue. Are you sure the code that handles the results is not expecting `ID ASC` and doing something like getting stuck in a loop "going the wrong direction"?

Comment: There seems to be a difference between my dev MySQL server and the production MySQL server. Running this code on the dev environment does not cause any issues.
@Uueerdo: You might be onto something; I will look into re-indexing the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be due to the result of the MySQL query.

When using `DESC`, the result was huge, and being processed by another function caused PHP to hang.

The result from `ASC` was different and smaller, so was not causing the same problem.